# How does one decrypt an encrypted Access Token? (OpenIddict 3.x)

Tags: c#, jwt, openid-connect, openiddict, jwe

OpenIddict, from version 3.x, encrypts access tokens by default, but you can disable this functionality. If the encryption is left re-enabled, is it possible for the client to decrypt the token or how would the client or relying party verify the access token?

So far, I have both signing and encryption keys stored in Azure Key Vault, which is accessed and used by the OpenIddict server through `RsaKeyVaultProvider`.

Comment: RSA has a public and private key, you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key

Comment: I grasp that. I guess that my question is how would the service provider verify an encrypted access token.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who needs to verify an encrypted token, needs to first decrypt it. So if you want to use encryption, you would have to provide the decryption key to the client or API. You could also implement some kind of introspection endpoint, which would accept the encrypted JWT, verify it and return either claims or just confirmation that the JWT is valid. Any client or API could then call this endpoint to verify the token, and you would only have to provide the decryption key to one party.

Any APIs which are accessed with this JWT can also have a gateway in front of them, which would decrypt the JWE and pass just the signed JWS.

Also remember that usually the client shouldn't be concerned about the validity of the token. The client just sends the token to the API, and either gets a correct response or not.

Normally I wouldn't go with encrypted tokens, unless you have a strong need for them. If you want to hide contents of tokens from any onlookers I would go with using opaque access tokens and implementing the [Phantom Token](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) pattern.

Comment: This does seem appropriate, and thank you for the reminder on the terminology. Do you know of any strong scenarios where the encrypted token might be of use, as opposed to a phantom token?

Comment: Decryption can be done offline. Phantom Token requires an online connection to the Authorization Server, so if that is an issue, then encryption might be more useful. There are also some financial-grade scenarios where encrypted tokens are required by regulators.